# Break-in engine

Tags: engine, break-in

I am going to buy new car Mitsubishi Pajero Sport (Model: MBS MT 4x4). I've heard stories of people 'breaking in' engines for the first few hundred or couple thousand kilometers using methods such as:

•   Not driving above 80 km/h.

•   Varying the revs more than usual throughout the entire range.

•   Keeping the revs below 2.5k.

Is 'break-in' necessary on modern cars? If so, how should I 'break-in' a new engine?

Thanks

Comment: The correct answer to this question is always to follow the manufacturer's recommendation.

The "break-in" procedures you describe originated long ago, and served a legitimate purpose,  but enormous advances in engineering, metallurgy, and lubricants mean much of that advice is obsolete for new cars.  

Note that I am not talking about a classic car with a newly rebuilt engine, I'm talking about a new factory vehicle. 

Most manufacturers I've seen do not recommend any special break-in procedure, they just tell you to take it a bit easy for the first X miles.

Comment: Consider that there's lots of other classic advice which once made sense, but is now meaningless. Smacking the carburetor to free up a stuck butterfly used to be common advice, but it doesn't make sense on a new car.

Comment: @barbecue - The problem is, unless you have a motorcycle, most manufacturers don't give you break-in instructions. There are still things you should and should not do during break-in ... old school or not.

Comment: Thanks a lot to your entire guide to give me usefully recommendation

Comment: @Paulster2, in my experience most manufacturers do provide some sort of "break-in" instructions in the owner's manual. It is usually something along the lines of "Don't drive like an idiot for the first 500 miles"

Comment: @barbecue - You've got me there :-)

Comment: Interestingly, the specific details do vary, but mostly the advice tends to be that for the first 500 miles or so, you should avoid hard acceleration, engine braking, and highway cruising.